# Upload multi files with curl

Tags: curl

I need help with command curl using POST. There may be many similar threads here, but none offer a solution to my problem. I want upload multi files with curl. When I add only one file works without problem, but when i try to upload many files with one command only first file uploaded. I use this command:

`curl --user xxxx:xxxx --request POST 'https://example.com/xxxx/xxxx?cmd=upload' --form "file=@dummy2.properties" --form "desc=myfiles" --form "file1=@dummy3.properties" --form "desc=myfiles"`

I tried too this command:

`curl --user xxxx:xxxx --request POST 'https://example.com/xxxx/xxxx?cmd=upload' --form "files=@dummy2.properties,dummy3.properties" --form "desc=myfiles"`

What is wrong?

Thank you.

I expect to upload multi files, but can upload only 1 files.

Answer (score 0):

I use postman for the request tests and from postman converting requests to the curl commands. To convert requests to curl use this link
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3m6cpQPsV0)

and for sending multiple files by curl use this sample:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:3000' \
--form 'images=@"/home/Pictures/Screenshot_20221016_164935.png"' \
--form 'images=@"/home/Pictures/Screenshot_20221009_114525.png"' \
--form 'images=@"/home/Pictures/Screenshot_20221008_143845.png"' \
--form 'images=@"/home/Pictures/Screenshot_20220912_135332.png"' \
--form 'images=@"/home/Pictures/Screenshot_20220822_120442.png"' \
--form 'images=@"/home/Pictures/2.png"' \
--form 'images=@"/home/Pictures/1.png"'
```

[image: request from postman and convert to curl]

Comment: Postman using only to generate the CURL command correctly. send 
a correct request by the postman and export the CURL command from it.